# asp.net use class in app_code folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

the index page I use is index.aspx and the c# class is called index.aspx.cs.

In the app_code folder I have another folder called "database" and within that folder is a .cs file called Query.cs

Now in the index.aspx.cs file I want to call the Query.cs class with the following code:

```
private Query query = new Query();
```

but it can't find Query.

What can I do?

Comment: Is Query the name of the class in that file? If so, is it public?

Comment: Maybe you're missing the namespace of the class...

Comment: The `App_Code` directory is special in ASP.NET and compiled at runtime, not design time. Program code contained within is only accessible from "code file" classes and `.aspx` files, not "code-behind" files

Comment: well, I can call the Query class in other .cs files in the app_code folder.

Comment: Try with the fully qualified name. Include the namespace: YourAppName.Query

Comment: I found the error, I coppied the class from another application so I removed the namespace and now it's working. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Below Example

Your `App_Code` Class File like below

```
public class Query
{
    public Datatable SelectData()
    {
        // Query Goes Here..
    }
}
```

Your `index.aspx.cs` file will be

```
//Create Object of Class
Query query = new Query();
Datatable dt = query.SelectData();
//Here Datatable is just considered for example
```

If you are calling class from another project you need give reference to that project.

Most of the times Access Modifiers are the issues in calling class members.